# Iterating through the lists

Tags: python

I have list of list

```
a = [[1, 2], [11, 22], [111, 222]]
```

I want output as  :

```
[1, 11,111]
[2, 22, 222]
```

how will I get that?

Comment: It is best to try some code, and post your error/output here along with your question - it shows you've made an effort first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = [[1, 2], [11, 22], [111, 222]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 11, 111), (2, 22, 222)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transpose in numpy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [11, 22], [111, 222]])
a.T
>>> array([[  1,  11, 111],
           [  2,  22, 222]])

a.T[0]
>>> array([  1,  11, 111])
a.T[1]
>>> array([  2,  22, 222])
```